# VsCode Plugin: Color Coding inline SQL in ts file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm new to the plugin world and I want to be sure to start in the right direction.
Starting from the vscode-extension-samples -> decorator-sample on github, 
I used a few regex with a combination of `vscode.Range`, `activeEditor.setDecorations` and a few minutes to achieve this:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this built-in in Vs-code than using dozens of regex ? Keep in mind that I'm in a .ts file.

Comment: did you end up open sourcing your solution by chance?

Comment: of course :) I ended up building a small extension for vs-code -> "mysql-inline-decorator". also available on Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no better way. Everything in the syntax highlighter is built around regular expressions. All the theme files use regex for patters that match particular text elements and assign them an id. And regex is not only used there but e.g. to recognize a file type.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll focus on regex